# Why do the values in the dictionaries in the list cascade update after changing the value by index

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am changing value in the dictionary on the list by index. But all the similar dictionaries in the list also update this key's value.
My code is.

```
 list=[]
 dict = {'id':2,'name':'hanna', 'age':30}
 list.append(dict)
 list.append(dict)
 list.append(dict) 
 list.append(dict)
 list.append(dict)
 list
```

Result

```
[{'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'}]
```

I want to change only this one

```
 list[0]['age']='99'
```

but this update all the dictionaries in the list also..

```
[{'age': '99', 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': '99', 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': '99', 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': '99', 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': '99', 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'}]
```

I need this

```
[{'age': 99, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'},
 {'age': 30, 'id': 2, 'name': 'hanna'}]
```

Why? And how change the value in the dict by index?

Comment: This is because of the mutable property of some objects in python. You can read here to understand it https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747

Comment: Wow! Thank you! This resolve my issue ! ` list.append(dict.copy())`

Comment: Thank you @nacho interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Even though this will be closed, I can understand that for a beginner the linked duplicate can be really confusing.

I just wanted to add a simpler explanation in the hope of helping you.

Basically, when you append to your list, it is the same object everytime.

Here is the proof,

```
list=[]
dict = {'id':2,'name':'hanna', 'age':30}
list.append(dict)
list.append(dict)
print(id(list[0]))
print(id(list[1]))
```

Example of output:

```
>>> 11301752
    11301752
```

So, when you're mutating the value after, you're actually doing it on the same object reference.

If you want more explanations on to how to overcome your problem definitely follow the duplicate link, it has a lot more information for you.

Comment: Thank you @scharette this is very clear now. Spend several hours trying to resolve this!

Answer (score 0):

Python passes arguments "by object", which means that what the called function gets is not a copy but the original object itself - IOW, your list contains n references to the very same dict instance, so however you access it (via the name `dict` or via `list[n]`), it's still the very same dict you're updating. Note that this works the same for bindings, ie `foo = {}; bar = foo` will not create a copy of `foo` but make both names point to the same dict. All this is very clearly explained [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

The cure is very obvious: make copies of the dict:

```
mydict = {"a":1}
mylist = []
mylist.append(mydict.copy())
mylist.append(mydict.copy())
mylist[1]["a"] = 42
print(mylist)
print(mydict)
```

Also note that `dict.copy()` returns a shallow copy. If your dict contains lists, other dicts or any mutable object, you may want a [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you @bruno desthuilliers! You know it is realy hard to search the answer for this problem from the novice point of view. Thanks again!